# How to make both readable and calculable Date/Time in shell script?

Tags: shell, datetime, aix

I am writing a shell script to track the start&end time of some running programs. I need the script to print both the readable start&end time and the time cost in seconds at last.

To calculate the cost, I write something like this

```
START=$(date +%s)
# ................
END=$(date +%s)
DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))
echo "Start Time: $START"  >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
echo "End Time: $END" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
echo "Running time: $DIFF seconds"  >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

This works for calculation, but the $START and $END can only be printed as number of seconds.

It's able to print readable date format if I define them like below

```
START=$(date +%c)
END=$(date +%c)
```

However, DIFF=$(( $END - $START )) doesn't work for them any more.

Therefore, I'm wondering if there're any solutions in shell script so that I can both print the date in defined format and do some calculations with them.

BTW, I am using AIX.

Comment: Why not using `time script.sh` to count how long does it take to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU date, you can use the epoch time

```
date -d @$START +%c
```

Otherwise, do

```
read start start_display < <(date +"%s %c")
# ...
read end end_display < <(date +"%s %c")
diff=$(( $end - $start ))
echo "Start time: $start_display"
```

If you're not using a shell capable of process substitution,

```
set -- $(date +"%s %c")
start=$1; shift
start_display=$*
```

If you use bash, take advantage of the builtin $SECONDS variable, which starts at zero for a new bash process and increments each second.

```
start_display=$(date)
# ...
echo "Start Time: $start_display"
echo "End Time: $(date)"
echo "Running time: $SECONDS seconds"
```

Comment: I'm really interested about ur second solution using 'read'. However, the syntax doesn't work in my system. I have to change it to `print $(date +"%s %c")|read start start_display`. Is it because I am using ksh?

Comment: Might be due to AIX, not sure. You don't need `print`: this will do `date +"%s %c" | read x y`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **date -d @Seconds** to convert seconds to date.
eg:

```
 $ date +%s
     1377095983
 $ date -d @1377095983
     Wed Aug 21 20:09:43 IST 2013
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I am using AIX 5.3 and its default shell is ksh. Does it support you commands?

Comment: Mybad, AIX doesn't come with gnu coreutils to support **-d -s -r -I -f** options with **date** command. You need to install [gnu coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) for these options to work.